# How to programmatically change the background color of the view

Tags: swift, xcode

For some reason whenever I load my app it either runs the background as white instead of the shade of red indicated in the rgb numbers. Any idea why?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253.0, green: 98.0, blue: 94.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Try dividing the r, g and b by 255.0

Comment: `UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 98/255, blue: 94/255, alpha: 1)`